# Git automatic checkout in subprojects

Tags: git, workflow

Enjoying the transition from SVN to **Git** in my company, we are rethinking our workflow and development process to be more effective.

Here is a description of dependencies between our projects :

```
first_app/
└── first_specific_dep
    └── common_dep

second_app/
└── second_specific_dep
    └── common_dep
```

- Both applications are interdependent, so a single user story can involve development in both projects.
- Multiple development can be achieved in the same time, so *feature branching* seems to be a good idea.
- In the same time, a development in a first level app can involve development in one or two dependencies.

We are looking for the better way to represent dependencies inside Git, especially when switching from a branch to another.

To be comfortable throughout all the development process, it is desirable that a **git checkout** in a root project automatically perform all other checkouts in sub-projects, so the testers would not worry about what are the branches of dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no magic bullet in this situation. Some tried to use Git submodules to solve that problem, but with mixed success as far as I know. (However, I have no experience myself, so I would welcome other options.)

In my current company, we just made the transition from CVS to Git, and we face the same challenge. There are two practical guidelines that we learned:

- If your feature branches often concern multiple repositories, you should consider to merge the repositories or reorganize the code. As a rough guideline, you should aim to have more than 90% of your development for a feature on one branch. Otherwise, the features are either too big, or the components (behind the repositories) are not well separated.
- Utility functions are indeed a problem, as you cannot avoid to share them between projects (that's their purpose). However, most of the time, they should be relatively stable. When you are developing inside your feature branch, it should occur relatively seldom that you need to modify the utility functions.

In other words, the better the logical structure of your code, the less you will stumble into the problems.

Finally, when in doubt whether to make split a repository or not, I would recommend to leave it in one repository. However, if you have a huge code base, it is not recommended to use one big repository, your pushes will often be rejected as non fast-forward.

We also build several scripts on top on Git to make it easier to checkout projects with all their dependences, but again, that depends very much on your environment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I’m not suprised by the absence of magic bullet, but I had to check for it. So, I’m going to merge the repositories.